# Sending id through select menu using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

here is my problem, I want to send id number through select menu using PHP. 
Here is the code:

```
<form name="update" method="post" action="ex_update.php?id=<?php echo ((int)$_POST['get_id']); ?>">
          <p><strong>Enter Name:</strong>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <br />
            ID: 
            <label for="select"></label>
            <select name="get_id">
            <?php 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
                $run = mysql_query($query);
                while($output = mysql_fetch_array($run)){
                echo "<option value=\"{$output['id']}\">{$output['id']}</option>";}
            ?>
            </select>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update!">
          </p>
        </form>
```

I have tried but when I submit the id in the URL equals to zero. how can I send id to the URL??

here is the ex_update.php >>>

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$sel_database = mysql_select_db("test");

$id = (int)$_GET["get_id"];
$name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["name"] );

$query = "UPDATE test SET name='{$name}' WHERE id=={$id}";
if($run = mysql_query($query)){

    }else{mysql_error();}


?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: silly question... My suggestion - Please read http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Comment: @knittl I know but i cant find any issue in this link that's why i have provided this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your First Page

Note action of form...

```
<form name="update" method="post" action="ex_update.php">
<p><strong>Enter Name:</strong>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br />
ID: 
<label for="select"></label>
<select name="get_id">
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
    $run = mysql_query($query);
    while($output = mysql_fetch_array($run)){
    echo "<option value=\"{$output['id']}\">{$output['id']}</option>";}
?>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update!">
</p>
</form>
```

And here you can find ex_update.php. Note: $id = (int)$_POST["get_id"];

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$sel_database = mysql_select_db("test");

$id = (int)$_POST["get_id"];
$name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["name"] );

$query = "UPDATE test SET name='{$name}' WHERE id={$id}";
if($run = mysql_query($query)){

    }else{mysql_error();}


?>
```

Comment: Its working code.. Note how you can pass parameter to your action script. You don't need to specify passing parameter in form action.

Comment: Thanks you very much Kamal, you rock!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form `GET` method

```
<form name="update" method="GET" action="ex_update.php">
```

You can access that select box value using `$_GET['get_id']` in `ex_update.php`